# Проблема с методом friends.get

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, api, методы

PHP код:

```
<?php
$token = "Скрыл";

$request_params = array(
'user_id' => $_GET['viewer_id'],
'fields' => 'first_name, last_name, domain, id, status',
'v' => '5.80',
'access_token' => $token
);

$request_params2 = array(
'user_id' => $_GET['viewer_id'],
'order' => 'count',
'v' => '5.80',
'access_token' => $token
);

$get_params = http_build_query($request_params);
$get_params2 = http_build_query($request_params2);
$result = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?'. $get_params));
$result2 = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/friends.get?'. $get_params2));
echo("Информация о тебе ");
echo("Имя: ".$result -> response[0] -> first_name." ");
echo("Фамилия: ".$result -> response[0] -> last_name." ");
echo("Ссылка на страницу: vk.com/".$result -> response[0] -> domain." ");
echo("ID: ".$result -> response[0] -> id." ");
echo("Статус: ".$result -> response[0] -> status." ");
echo("Друзей: ".$result2 -> response[0] -> count);
?>
```

Что не так?
Не показывает количество друзей.

Comment: мм скорее всего у пользователя которого вы хотите просмотреть, в настройках приватности стоит галочка не показывать друзей

Comment: Выходит следующая ошибка: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in (путь) Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in (путь) on line 28

Answer (score 0):

Убрал в response[0] "[0]" и всё работает.